# How to use Normal constructor correctly in pymc3?

Tags: anaconda, pymc3

When I use pymc3 to construct a normal distribution, I got error message. How to solve this problem?

I installed PyMC3 with windows Anaconda (version Anaconda3-2019.03-Windows-x86_64.exe). And running codes from official pymc3 tutorial "Getting started with PyMC3".

I tried to build a normal distribution with Normal constructor pm.Normal().  The codes are listed below

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

basic_model = pm.Model()

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal('alpha', mu=0, sigma=10)
```

But got error message as the following:

AttributeError: module 'numpy.core.multiarray' has no attribute '_get_ndarray_c_version'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by removing theano 1.0.3 from Anaconda and performing pip install the latest version >=1.0.4.